# When uploading a large repo, is it ok to create and checkout a new branch in another terminal tab while the repo finishes uploading?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Scenario is that the master branch is being sent up to say GitHub/Bitbucket, but is taking awhile.  Can I, in another terminal tab, create checkout and work on a new branch while the master branch is being uploaded without breaking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can only thing is new branch changes will not be reflected in your git repository until you have commit the new changes on Server. Also It is better to create a new branch first and then upload the directory. Then you can start working on the new branch when upload is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

git is meant to be safe with concurrent use. If some cannot be used concurrently it would report an error.

In your case, I think it should be always possible to check out at least local branch without accessing remote-tracking references, or with accessiong those which you are not pushing